# How to call parent's method in custom render component on handsontable/vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, handsontable

**Description**

I am using custom render in hotTable.
In the custom renderer component, I want to call the parent's method when clicking an icon.
I tried to use event and props but both of them did not work.

Anyone please let me know solution.

**Demo**

**Methods as props**

Home.vue

```
<hot-table :data="hotTableData" :autoRowSize="false" :autoColumnSize="false">
         <hot-column title="Character" width="350">
             <first-column method="handleUp" hot-renderer></first-column>
          </hot-column>                     
</hot-table>

......................................................................
......................................................................

import FirstColumn from "./FirstColumn.vue";

......................................................................
......................................................................

methods: {
    handleUp(id) {
         console.log(id);
    }
}
```

FirstColumn.Vue

```
<template>
    <div>
          <div style="width: 30px;">
                <div style="height: 22px; line-height: 22px;">
                    <span v-on:click="upUserValue(value)"
                            class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>
                </div>
                <label>{{value}}</label>
            </div>
    </div>
</template>

 <script>
 export default {
     props: {
         method: { type: Function },
     },
     data: function() {
         return {
             hotInstance: null,
             row: null,
             col: null,
             value: 0
         }
     },
     methods: {
         upUserValue(character_id) {
             this.method(character_id);
         }
     }
 }
 </script>
```

*Error: this.method is not a function*

**Events**

Home.vue

```
<hot-table :data="hotTableData" :autoRowSize="false" :autoColumnSize="false">
               <hot-column title="Character" width="350">
                   <first-column @onUpUserValue="handleUp" hot-renderer></first-column>
               </hot-column>
</hot-table>

......................................................................
......................................................................

method: {
    handleUp (event, id) {
            console.log(id);
     },
}
```

FirstColumn.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
          <div style="width: 30px;">
                <div style="height: 22px; line-height: 22px;">
                    <span v-on:click="upUserValue(value)"
                            class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>
                </div>
                <label>{{value}}</label>
            </div>
    </div>
</template>

 <script>
 export default {
     props: {
         method: { type: Function },
     },
     data: function() {
         return {
             hotInstance: null,
             row: null,
             col: null,
             value: 0
         }
     },
     methods: {
         upUserValue(character_id) {
             this.$emit('onUpUserValue', character_id);
         }
     }
 }
 </script>

No Result
```

Your environment

Vue wrapper version: ^2.5.7

Handsontable version: ^7.4.2

@handsonetable/vue version: ^4.1.1

Browser Name and version: Chrome

Operating System: Windows 10

Comment: This is demo. https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-elion-v7x8i

Comment: Did you find a solution?